# After exporting flowchart in MS Word as PDF some lines turn bold

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, pdf, flowchart

I'm doing a flowchart. While in Word it looks normal:

[image]

Yet after I export it into PDF, some lines turn bold. I'm using Windows 7 and MS Word 2013. To export I use save as PDF option.

[image: IMG:]

How can I export my flowchart into PDF looking as it is?

Comment: Does the effect persist when you zoom in?

Comment: What version of Windows and Word are you using exactly? What method exactly are you using to export to PDF? Please explain with more detail to paint the clearest picture you can. Just [edit] you question and add these details plus anything else you can think of that'd be helpful.